# angular.foreach function throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop, foreach

function getTotal.getValues() is a server call that returns "one", "two", "three" ... "nine". i can print them with console.log(res). however, it seems i cannot push them into variable v created inside runTest Function. in this code, console.log(r) does not print anything because return v is empty. any ideas?

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

        function runTest(val) {
            var v = [];
            val.forEach(function(t) {
                getTotal.getValues(t).then(function(res) {
                    //console.log(res);
                    v.push(res);
                });
            });
            return v;
        }
        runTest(test).forEach(function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        });
```

Comment: Your syntax looks fine to me. Are you sure it's a syntax error you're getting?

Comment: yes, i'm still getting the same error. syntax error, $injector could not initiate ...

Comment: If it was a syntax error, it would be saying something like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. The code above cannot be producing the error you're reporting.

Comment: ok Mike, this i was setting my test variable in a function out side of my controller, then returning the result and grabbing it inside controller, syntax error is gone. i have another problem, let me update my question ...

Comment: I have edited the question after your hint, this is where i mean by foreach does not work. v.push(res) seems to be not working, however i can print res values with console.log(res)

Answer (score 1):

Are you mistaken between angular [**forEach**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) and javascript [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Angular forEach should be like this. I can't see angular forEach I your code snippet.

```
angular.forEach(test, function(value, key) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your forEach function should look like:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
test.forEach(function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
});
// logs:
// a[0] = 1
// a[1] = 2
// a[2] = 3
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

But if you want to use angular.forEach(), refer to:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Good luck!